# Why does my Android Studio gradle throw an error when adding an external library?

Tags: android, gradle

I want to include a library in Android Studio , but it displays error like below :
implementation 'Io.alter ac.blur kit:blur kit:1.1.0'
How to fix this problem?

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 33
        buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId ""
            minSdkVersion 33
            targetSdkVersion 33
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                determinable false
                profiteroles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-ptimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }
dependencies {

     compile 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
     compile 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
     compile 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
     compile 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
     compile 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
     compile 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to include the error.